# Why does HashMap allow duplicates and StringBuilder does not reverse properly?

Tags: java, hashmap, stringbuilder

HashMap should not allow duplicates, while StringBuilder.reverse() does not work properly. Why?

```
String s = "abba";
static int myMethod(String s) {
        int counter = 0;
        Map<StringBuilder, StringBuilder> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int j = 0; j <= s.length(); j++) {
            for (int i = j + 1; i <= s.length(); i++) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.substring(j, i));
                map.put(sb, sb.reverse());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("map " + map);
        return counter;
    }
```

Output:

map {bba=bba, ba=ba, b=b, a=a, a=a, ab=ab, abb=abb, abba=abba, b=b, bb=bb}

Comment: It is a bad idea to use mutable objects as keys in maps (in this case `StringBuilder`)  If those objects get changed you may not be able to retrieve the stored value from the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't store `StringBuilder` in the `HashMap`, because unlike `String` it does not implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods based on its content (it inherits them from `Object`). Two different instances of a `StringBuilder` can never be equal. In order for the program to function properly and prevent duplicates, store `String` instead:

```
String s = "abba";
int counter = 0;
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int j = 0; j <= s.length(); j++) {
     for (int i = j + 1; i <= s.length(); i++) {
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.substring(j, i));
          StringBuilder reverse = sb.reverse();
          map.put(s.substring(j, i), reverse.toString());
     }
}
System.out.println("map " + map);
```

Output:

```
map {abb=bba, bb=bb, bba=abb, a=a, ab=ba, b=b, abba=abba, ba=ab}
```

Answer (score 4):

`HashMap` doesn't allow duplicates. But it's a question of how those duplicates are determined as to why you might think it does.

It uses `hashCode()` and `equals()` to determine if two things are the same. `StringBuilder` overrides neither, and so uses the implementations from `Object`, which are based on identity. As such, two distinct instances of `StringBuilder` - irrespective of the contents of the internal buffer - are unequal.

---

`reverse()` is reversing the `StringBuilder` in place. As such, `sb` and `sb.reverse()` are the same `StringBuilder`.

Obviously, the same instance can only have its characters in a single order. What you are seeing here is that you are storing the reversed string as both the key and value.